# Best way to display information to a ListFragment?

Tags: android, xml, text, file-io, android-listfragment

I am creating an app for my campus news paper and one of the features will be a tab with a list of all the clubs and organizations on campus. I am wondering what the best way to do this would be. I currently use an RSS handler to fetch new articles from the website in another tab, but the information on the clubs and organizations is not on an RSS feed anywhere. 
[image]

I am wondering what the best way to put this information into a list would be? I initially thought the simplest way would be with a text file, or by xml file. Ideally I would like for the list item to show the club's short name and the full name under it, like I have the article name and pub date in the articles tab. Such as IEEE and under it Institute of Electrical and Electronic Engineers.

When a list item is clicked I want to launch a detail view with the clubs logo and a description. I would like to know if anyone has done something like this before and knows the best way to do this.

I think it would be possible to create my own XML file and parse it like I already did for the news articles, but I am not sure, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Nice edit. But I think we could help if you'd provide more details with your problem. The question is so general.

Comment: Well I guess that is the problem, I am really just looking for advice on the best way to put information into a ListFragment. I could show what I did to parse an RSS feed, because I essentially want to mimic that but with offline information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to create my own XML file and read it from the assets folder, pretty much the same method I used for the RSS feed but with a different InputSource.